Link between photon helicity and polarization of $A^\mu$ electromagnetic potential
From Wigner theorem we know that the irreducible unitary representation of the Poincarè group for massless and spin 1 particle is labelled by the momentum $p_\mu$ and the two possible helicity $+1,-1$ (Wu-Ki Tung book "Group theory in physics" page 198-199).
We also know that in QFT the electromagnetic potential $A^\mu$ can have only two orthogonal polarizations $\epsilon^\mu_1(p)$ and $\epsilon^\mu_2(p)$ (Schwartz book "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" page 126).
I guess this matching "two" values are not casual.
Is there any QFT results that explains the link between the two helicity of the photon and the two polarization of the electromagnetic field?

What are you even asking about? Even on Wikipedia you can find that the polarisations that correspond to helicity = chirality = circular polarisation, and even talks about the conflicting conventions between quantum physics and the optics literature. $\epsilon$ that you see in the Schwartz book can be chosen to be circular polarisation too, though we usually pick linear polarisations for that.

Basecally I am wondering about a theoretical/mathematical link between the helicity of the photon and the polarization of the electromagnetic field

This is discussed in Weinberg’s The Quantum Theory of Fields chapter 5. It has to do with encoding the massless spin one unitary irrep of the Poincare group (creation/annihilation operators of photons) in a field transforming in the vector representation of the Lorentz group. It is actually a quite nice thing because the necessity of gauge invariance appears naturally.

errm, as gold said, I am pointing you directly to that link. The exact mathematical expressions that satisfy the theoretical needs for that link so that they can connect exactly to experiments. What more did you want? It is an identification of the mathematical structures that work correctly, not an explanation of why that link exists. The job of a theory is only to assert a specific mathematical representation works; it is not to explain exactly why it has to be that link. If you were looking for a philosophical reason, you are out of luck.

Such encoding of the unitary irrep for massless spin 1 particles into the field is not clear to me. What is the vector space of the rep in this case? How are built the operators of the Poincarè group? I will try to read Weinberg may there I get the pieces I am missing

An electron is both an electric charge and a magnetic dipole. The same applies to a positron. However, they differ not only in their charge and their direction of deflection in the magnetic field. The helicity of the electron-magnetic radiation of the electron is orientated in the opposite direction to the helicity of the EM radiation of the positron.
